Exportable Sharepoint Document Version#
I have an excel file with VBA which needs to know the latest released version number of a sharepoint document. I have done an export to excel from my library, into a sheet where the data connection is refreshed every time the sheet is opened.
Noted that version # can't be directly exported, so created a calculated field to pick it up.
I just updated a document and noted that the calculated field is "0". I understand the reason for this, but what can I do so that my Excel worksheet can discover the current version of each document in the library? I have tried creating a scheduled flow to copy the version over to a new exportable field, but I can't update the value without checking out - which defeats the whole purpose if it changes the version number.
Note I am not a sharepoint admin, but I do manage this particular library and a few others.
The above excel document needs to be used by many users and will be stored on a network drive.
I have tried the powershell script but I get "No snap-ins have been registered" error and don't have privileges to install snap-ins - and obviously neither do the many users of the Excel file.
Any help is appreciated.

You can try to turn off the Check in/Check out function to see if your needs can be met. I don't know how you did it, but according to the information you provided, if you still want to edit the file, even if you don't enable the Check in/Check out function, a new version will be generated after editing. Or you can provide more details about this matter.

